# Should downvoting be enabled by competence on spec tags rather than reputation points only?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes, voting

I am fairly new to Stack Overflow and experienced a **'meta effect'** on one of my questions, I'm also fairly new in 'my' scripting community which is **[TYPO3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPO3)**...

I agree that is an explosive mix for fairly stupid/incomplete questions and little familiarity with rules and practices, **BUT** being long-time in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) and [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) I know that these stupid questions are **useful for a community** seen the very steep access curve to this [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) ... (most of 'us' struggle there)

The 'snap-judgement' I received (I was downvoted, otherwise I would not give it any thought, but I'm not whining) was probably from users that are competent in other fields and communities, so **they did earn their reputation, but might not be aware of the particular difficulties or usefulness** of a question in the area of typo3...

I say this because I would have never suspected the kind of difficulties TYPE3 would have given me when I accepted my position **6 months** ago, and I'm **still a beginner !!**, (in 1997 it took that time and I wrote my own CMS from scratch) just to underline the effort something might take that looks fairly simple for a community that has many users and much docs for entry-level...

Of course I am talking from the 'side-line', and I do have much respect for the great work done on Stack Overflow, I did get great backup through this, and I'm participating because of this ... I probably oversee some consequences, but it looks fair to me that **downvoting should also be reserved to users that have earned the tags involved**, rather than only a reputation...

That also gives the author of the question a responsibility to supply the proper tags to avoid 'general judgement'...

I do hope this is a worthwhile reflection to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9CHQ.jpg

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks buddy, it should indeed remain fun !!!

Comment: Downvotes on meta do nothing. They're merely an indication of agreement/disagreement/whatever you feel like. They don't affect rep, and you won't ever get QBanned from downvotes on meta.

Comment: @Magisch I know ... I was new and genuine enough to link to my question as example ... somehow there was a general dislike and I ended up with devastated rep ... not only in meta

Comment: If a new technology appears nobody you're suggesting that nobody would be able to provide feedback on whether any questions asked about it were bad (at least until we got some badge holders in it). That doesn't seem a useful feature.

Comment: @RobertLongson within a new technology one could quickly earn the tag with relatively basic stuff ...

Comment: To avoid downvotes I'll simply create a new tag for every question I ask then.

Comment: @RobertLongson you're right ... as a newcomer I do not forsee the 'smart byways' then again its fair to rule for the right kind of persons and shunt the bad ones in another way ...

Comment: newcomers are expected to reseach the previous times this kind of thing has been asked, downvoted and rejected before on this site. Old timers can simply use their memory. That's the only real difference. You're not just getting downvotes because people disagree, you're getting them for lack of research.

Comment: @RobertLongson what you miss is that a newcomer usually is pretty weak on his own job too, and needs to read up on a lot ... that's not an excuse but ... this remains a forum with humans ...

Comment: No, it's not a forum at all. There's plenty of questions and answers clarifying that too.

Comment: @RobertLongson ok, I overstepped my competence ... You do have the credit to state what you do, and you are probably right !! mine is a real question so I should not pretend to know it all ...

Comment: @RobertLongson reading the comments once more, a new subject would be open to feedback, comments and upvoting can do a lot, and the power of downvote doesn't get lost since there will be soon enough a good number of users having the right to 'clean up' the arena ...

Comment: The tag would quickly end up a mess as lots of bad questions would accumulate and it would not be possible to delete them.

Comment: Well clearly if we can't trust people to downvote without experience in the tag to know that they're knowledgeable then naturally we couldn't trust them to upvote either, no?  I mean, if it requires a certain amount of experience to know what content isn't helpful, it should require that much experience to know what *is* helpful.

Comment: @Servy that's probably right, so basically you could agree ?

Comment: @webman I didn't say that, I just said that it should be both or neither, not just one.  It's still full of other problems.

Comment: @RobertLongson If one where to invent new tags to avoid 'judgement' he would also avoid the attention that the pertinent tags would draw ...

Comment: A lot of the time you don't even need to be an "expert" on a certain tag to know a question is bad. I barely ever use .Net but I certainly know if a question is too broad or lacking in a certain way regardless of how well I know the subject.

Comment: @patricksweeney the trouble I had with typo3 was unsuspected, that might be my personal unprepared state, but I assure you that I would honestly appreciate a lot of Q/A's worked out on basic typo3 stuff like I did ... that might seem 'run of the mill' but I assure you that is not the case, there are so many errors possible and frequently only one exact right way to go about ...

Answer (score 12):

I'm guessing you're talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539413/typo3-add-special-menu-and-add-class-active) question, since it's your only visible downvoted one.

The meta effect is a particular beast. It's not always helpful, but it boils down to essentially increased attention on a question or answer. If it is good, this often results in lots of upvotes, perhaps unduely. If it is bad, then it often results in lots of downvotes.

People also tend to downvote on main because of a person's behavior on meta, which strictly speaking isn't the purpose of votes. But generally, it results in more eyeballs on the post and more people to judge it.

Your question was indeed quite poor, and it didn't take a expert in typo3 to see this. It showed no prior research effort, no attempt of your own, basicly just a variant of "please show me how this is done", in and of itself not very good.

Now, in a normal environment, not a lot of people might have seen this question. But you linked it, so lots of people saw and downvoted accordingly.

Your rep isn't "devastated" however. You got downvoted on one post. That entire ordeal cost you about 24 rep in total, or roughly 2 and a half answer-upvotes worth. You can recover from this. Just read the [help center page on how to ask a nice, on topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first next time.

As for your suggestion, no. There shouldn't be a limit to downvoting other then the ones we already have. There are lots of questions where you can easily see that they're poor quality even if you have absolutely no clue about the subject matter, and people exercising their down votes is our primary means of quality control on this site.

Comment: you are right, that is the question and you are wrong ... id did take me a lot of research, what you underestimate is the syntax in typo3, that is extremely precise combined with advanced caching and complex debugging ... so I wound up doing the right thing but not have the results due to cache ... furthermore it strikes from typoscript to fluid, so many errors possible that I still get a head-ache thinking about how I got the result

Comment: @webman In that case, it's always nice to show your prior effort in the question, to make it easier for people to see where you tripped up and easier for future visitors who tripped up at the same place. The help center page I linked mentions that.

Comment: anyhow, its very nice to have your answer, I'm not going to vote it for the moment, but for me you make SO worthwhile

Comment: I will still do this, I'm 'stuck with this question' so I'll continue to work it untill its 100% worthwhile ...

Comment: you are right, the thing that triggered mostly my 'reflection' was that **a wrong answer** was upvoted (if you know typo3, btw no need to down elvis, he did do his effort and gives valuable info, just not a right answer) and mine no vote although its right, I think something should be done about that, but there are surely users with lost more experience and vision to say what ...

Comment: @webman i have to say "don't downvote" if the answer is wrong shows you still don't grasp what Stack is about. No one will be downvoting Elvis... We'll be downvoting the bad content. It's seriously super easy to take DVs personally... It's not how it should be.

Comment: @Patrice, hi patrice, I assure you at this point it was not that I take it personally, I have a strong urge for justice wherever that might take me ... this is a computer community, no space for opinions so read my question and the answers and try to make that work ... at that point I rest my case (and would like to have a comment from the upvoter who retained that elvis should draw attention with that answer)

Comment: @magisch ... you do have sound reasoning but why did you link to my question? in this discussion my question should have been irrelevant, but never the less my question is voted, that seems rather more personal than analytic (ever more because still NO COMMENTS enrich my knowledge of why)...

Comment: @webman Because I partly discuss the merits of your question (lack of posted research) in my answer.

Comment: @Magisch  that sounds reasonable, its kind of sad though that the value of my question is still voted trough this channel, that should be discouraged, there is a certain follow by example, I get that this is a sore spot in the Stack, but I can't see that my question is that clear case of this ...

Comment: @magisch could you please advice me if I should delete this question ? the 'poll' turned out that many (including yourself) do not see value in this way of looking at business ... In this case has it any value to leave the question up ?

Comment: @webman You couldn't delete the question even if you tried, as it has an answer, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @Servy thanks, I did not know this ... the question I did delete had indeed only downvotes ... just know that my interest in deleting was not 'to cover my traces' or so, it seems useless to leave if it does not meet any consent, the answer did though so that might have value !

Comment: very curious to experience certain key-comments triggering downvoting straight up on my question ...